# Send Body React Native - PHP

Tags: react-native

I am sending the clientid variable in my React-native project. I am sending the body using the post method when posting.But now the clientid variable is not going to php, it sends a null value.

**React-Native Code**

```
 let rspNew = await get3dNumber({
                clientid: "500300000",
                ...
            })


export function get3dNumber(CART){
    return fetch(`http://...php`,{
        method:'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
                             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        },
         redirect:'follow',
        body:JSON.stringify(CART)
    })
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, X-Requested-With");
    
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    
    $myArray = array();
    $myArray['clientid'] = $json['clientid']; 
    ?>
```

Comment: If you print out `file_get_contents('php://input')` on the server what do you get?

Comment: I print out the value : 0

Comment: Your content type doesn't match your content header.  Try changing your header to this:

`headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
  },`

Comment: I still have the same problem

Comment: I wonder why you are using `file_get_contents` on the server side.  I don't know PHP but isn't that for reading a file?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fetch data from my PHP API

```html
 fetch('http://...php',{
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers :{
                     Accept: 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                 },
                 body: JSON.stringify({
                    key: data,
                    key2:data
                 })
             })
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then( (responseJson)=> {
               console.log(responseJson)
             });
```

in PHP  page

```html
$obj   =json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$key = (!empty($obj['key'])) ? trim($obj['key']) : '' ;
$key2 = (!empty($obj['key2'])) ? trim($obj['key2']) : '' ;
```